# Error while parsing a string that I receive from backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I'm currently using ChartJS for displaying a chart and in that, I'm receiving all the data from the backend. The problem is that the options properties like chart header, yaxis ticks, etc aren't being added to the chart.

Here is my Universal Chart component:

```
class UniversalChart extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}
chartRef = React.createRef();



componentDidMount() {

    const myChartRef = this.chartRef.current.getContext("2d");
    console.log('options Data inside Uni Chart',this.props.options);
    

    new Chart(myChartRef, {
        type: this.props.type,
        data: { labels: this.props.labels, datasets: this.props.data },
        options: this.props.options
    })
}

render() {
    return <canvas ref={this.chartRef} height={this.props.height} />
}

}
```

Here is data that I receive from options inside of my Universal Chart component: {"responsive":true,"title":{"display":true,"text":"Sales trend"},"legend":{"position":"bottom"},"scales":{"yAxes":[{"ticks":{"beginAtZero":true,"stepSize":20}}]}}

Here is a screenshot of the console log:
[image]

Also, here is the screenshot of the chartOptions data that I receive in the ChartBox component and which I pass it down to Universal chart.

[image]

I pass down the data to Universal Chart component from the parent ChartBox component like this:

```
   <UniversalChart
                            type={props.data.chart_data_config.chartType}
                            data={props.data.datasets}
                            labels ={props.data.labels}
                            options={props.data.chart_data_config.chartOptions}
                            height={props.data.chart_data_config.height}
                        />
```

I also tried this inside my Universal Chart comp:

```
options: JSON.parse(this.props.options)
```

But that's giving me a cross-origin error: Uncaught Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development.

Please let me know the solution to the problem. I want the UniversalChart comp to read the options json that I'm passing to show the chart header and utilize the other properties.

Comment: Are you sure the json is valid, can you parse it in the console because that can throw the error. When I try to pass a tring to a child I dont get the error unless its invalid json. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-forked-r1tv7?file=/index.js

Comment: I get an error when I try to parse it like I mentioned in my question. I don't know why I get the error. I've posted the screenshots so that you can see the exact data I'm receiving the 2 components. The other things like data, labels, etc are being passed correctly, no issues with that, only the options part is giving me a headache.

Comment: Yeah I can see the data you receive in the prop, but it's a screenshot and a lot of text so people won't type it over, takes long time and high chance of mistake. That's why I asked you if it's valid JSON because that could be your problem.

Comment: Here is the data in the ChartBox comp. You can see the same in the screenshot as well: "{"responsive":true,"title":{"display":true,"text":"Sales trend"},"legend":{"position":"bottom"},"scales":{"yAxes":[{"ticks":{"beginAtZero":true,"stepSize":20}}]}}"